# Latest Nivo Slider 3.2 transitions not working in ie7 and ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, nivo-slider

I've just downloaded the latest Nivo slider 3.2 as I need it on a responsive site and out of the box with no modifications the transitions in ie7 and ie8 don't work.

They simply flick between images - no sliceDown or Fade they just rotate.

I've used it in the past with no problems - I've just view 2.6 in ie7 and ie8 and it's fine.

Does anyone know what can be done to fix it?

I've just checked out their demo too http://nivo.dev7studios.com/responsive-demo/ and the same issue is happening there.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing what worked on my site -- I was using the default demo code, pretty much unedited from the download. It was beautiful and responsive (which I wanted) in all of the browsers I tested, except any version of i.e.. If i.e., it was just a rotation, no effects.

However, when I designated a size dimension for the wrapper div *and* the image divs, the transitions worked in i.e. also. (height: 350px;) You can specify the dimension in your css/stylesheet or inline -- if that's what it takes.

On my site, I only needed to specify a height dimension; for your site, you might need both height and width, or just width. A little experimentation was all it took.

But, with the height dimension specified, this threw off the display in the other browsers, so the dimension needs to be specified in terms of a "hack" for internet explorer: either a separate stylesheet just for internet explorer users or by using whatever your favorite internet explorer hacking method is: underscore, or  \9, and so on. Here's a list of useful internet explorer workarounds, just for reference: [internet explorer hacks](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks)

I know we hate to recommend hacking, but we all do it :). Would love to find out why this one worked for me, maybe there's a better way without the hack.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to stackoverflow! Thank you for your contribution. Could you please edit your answer to look more like an answer, emphasizing what solves OP's solution and how?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. My hack free solution was get another slideshow :)
I ended up finding http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/ which works great in IE and the transitions are really lovely and smooth with a large variety of transitions. To me it actually displays better then Nivo so I'll stick with this one for future jobs if they require a responsive slider.